# onChange is not getting the disabled input value to state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi i am trying to pass a custom value created from a state and adding them to the xero_code input value as shown below.

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  type="text"
  name="xero_code"
  onChange={(e) =>
    handleChangeLevel3(
      e,
      i,
      index,
      "product_information",
      "order_list_products"
    )
  }
  value={
    spreadList.machine +
    "" +
    data.product_name +
    "" +
    spreadList.spreadRate +
    "." +
    spreadList.location
  }
  defaultvalue={"inputValue"}
  placeholder="Xero Code"
  disabled 
/>;
```

Below i have added the onChange event

```
const handleChangeLevel3 = (e, i, j, arrayname, arrayname2) => {
    setDirty()
    const { name, value } = e.target
    const list = { ...inputList }

    list[arrayname][i][arrayname2][j][name] = value
    setInputList(list)
    handleXeroCode()
  }
```

The value changes as expected but it's not being added to the state object! The onChange is not triggering the event!

But if i to remove disabled attribute and type over it the value updates the state.
How can i trigger the onChange and make this work?

Below i have added the structure of my State!

[image]

Comment: Where are you using `disabled` attribute? I don't see it.

Comment: I am sorry i must have remove it for testing purposes! I have updated the code! Please have a look

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue correctly, but `onChange` isn't triggered when value changes. It's only triggered when you actually interact with the input (type, clear paste to it etc.). And there is clearly no interaction with the `disabled` field.

Comment: Exactly! The value changes during interaction but i want it to work without any interactions..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do something weird there. Can you describe what you're trying to do from the beginning? Not in code, just say what your app does.

Comment: I have states that hold data from multiple tables which allows the user to select the required products that generates a dynamic code and this code will generate a price for each product! It’s not a single one multiple products..

Comment: I have a feeling that you don't yet fully understand how React works and how to write optimal React code. But I'll try to help. Consider using `useEffect()` to listen to this value change, but I'm assuming your other code is structured in sensible way, which I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, the code is quite messy! Using an useEffect might slow down the speed of retrieving data as there are many api running at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code for "handleChangeLevel3"

```
const handleChangeLevel3 = (e, i, j, arrayname, arrayname2) => {
    setDirty()
    const { name, value } = e.target
    let list = { ...inputList }
    let newObj = { ...list[arrayname][i][arrayname2][j], [name]: value }
    let newArrName2 = [...list[arrayname][i][arrayname2]]
    newArrName2[i] = { ...newObj }
    let newArrName = [...list[arrayname]]
    newArrName[i] = { ...newArrName2 }
    list = { ...list, [arrayname]: [...newArrName] }
    setInputList(list)
    handleXeroCode()
  }
```

here you need to use deep copy to change value.
In your case react didn't detect change. as it use virtual dom and compare it with real dom but sometimes at this level of change you need to use deep copy concept instead of shallow copy.

Comment: Hi i have updated the question with an image of my structure of LIST

Comment: please check I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer above. I have tried it but still the onchange is not setting the value .. works as same as the previous code i have applied!